# Way to use react-router and redux on react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, redux, react-redux

I'm started to use react-native (i'm from react-js), and i'm trying to implement my first little app with a router and redux as I do in web development with reactjs.

But i met a problem, and i can't to fix it.

so i'm on this way :

Index.ios.js

```jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { NavBar, Route, Router, Schema, TabBar, TabRoute } from 'react-native-router-redux';

import configureStore from './src/store/configureStore'
const store = configureStore()

import Index from './src/components/index'

class ole extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
        <Router initial="index">
        <Route name="index" component={Index} />
        </Router>
        </Provider>
      )
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ole', () => ole);
```

store/configureStore.js

```jsx
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import promise from 'redux-promise'
import reducer from '../reducers'

export default function configureStore(initialState){
    const store = createStore(
        reducer,
        applyMiddleware(promise)
    )
    return store
}
```

reducers/index.js

```jsx
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    test: [],
    errors: undefined
}

initTestReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    return state
}

export default combineReducers({
    test: initTestReducer
})
```

if do exactly like that i get this error in my simulator on iOS :

> Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

but if my index.ios.js look like that, it works perfectly :

```jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { NavBar, Route, Router, Schema, TabBar, TabRoute } from 'react-native-router-redux';

import configureStore from './src/store/configureStore'
const store = configureStore()

import Index from './src/components/index'

class ole extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
        <Index />
        </Provider>
      )
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ole', () => ole);
```

So error come from **Router**

get u an idea ?

Thank's a lot :)

Comment: That error happens when you try to extend something that is not a class.
Can you please post your Index component module? Does it have a ```export default``` in it?

Comment: What line causes the error?